# System call read result display random characters after the result

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, unistd.h

I've recieved this assignment where I have to read from a file.txt(max size 4096B) four times, basically splitting it in 4 strings of equal size. I have to fill this structure(just consider field 'msg', i think the problem is there):

```
struct message {
    
    long mtype
    int nclient; 
    int pid;     
    char path[151];
    char msg[1025];
};
```

I used an array of 4 `struct message` to store all 4 parts

This is my read:

```
struct message msgs[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        msgs[i].nclient=pos+1;
        msgs[i].mtype = 42;
        msgs[i].pid = getpid();
        strcpy(msgs[i].path, filespath[pos]);
        if (read(fd, msgs[i].msg, nMsgSize[i]) == -1)
            ErrExit("read failed");
        printf("I've read: %s\nMSGSize: %d\nPath: %s\n",msgs[i].msg, nMsgSize[i], msgs[i].path);
    }
```

I tested it on a file "sendme_5.txt" that has this text in it:

> ABCD

And this is my output:

> I've read: A MSGSize: 1 Path:
> /home/luca/Desktop/system_call_meh/myDir/joe_bastianich/bruno_barbieri/sendme_5.txt
>
> I've read: BP"�> MSGSize: 1 Path:
> /home/luca/Desktop/system_call_meh/myDir/joe_bastianich/bruno_barbieri/sendme_5.txt
>
> I've read: C#��;�U MSGSize: 1 Path:
> /home/luca/Desktop/system_call_meh/myDir/joe_bastianich/bruno_barbieri/sendme_5.txt
>
> I've read: D�.�>� MSGSize: 1 Path:
> /home/luca/Desktop/system_call_meh/myDir/joe_bastianich/bruno_barbieri/sendme_5.txt

If i try to read the full file without dividing it in 4(with only one read), it displays it correctly.

The problem started when i changed the field `char path[151]`. We had to set the max size to 151 from PATH_MAX(4096) after a change in the assignment, but i dont know if it's related.

What is the problem here?

Comment: The `read()` system call doesn't null terminate strings — it has no clue what a string is.  So, unless you initialize your structure, you get what's read plus whatever garbage was in the structure before the `read()` call.

Comment: If you want to know the best way to fix this, then please post a full runnable program instead of just a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) does not know what a [null-terminated string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) is. It deals with raw bytes, making no assumptions about the data it reads.

As is, your strings are possibly not null-terminated. `printf("%s", msgs[i].msg)` might continue past the the end of the read data, possibly past the end of the buffer, searching for a null-terminating byte. Unless the data read happens to contain a null-terminating byte, or the buffer was zeroed-out beforehand (and not completely filled by `read`), this is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

On success, [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) returns the number of bytes read into the buffer. This may be less than requested. The return value is of type [`ssize_t`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/system_data_types.7.html).

When using this system call to populate string buffers, the return value can be used to index and place the null-terminating byte. An additional byte should always be reserved for this case (that is, always read at most the size of the buffer minus one: `char buf[256]; read(fd, buf, 255)`).

Always check for error, or the return value of `-1` will index the buffer out-of-bounds.

Assuming `nMsgSize[i]` is the exact size of the `msgs[i].msg` buffer:

```
ssize_t n;
                                                            
if (-1 == (n = read(fd, msgs[i].msg, nMsgSize[i] - 1)))
    ErrExit("read failed");
    
msgs[i].msg[n] = 0;
    
printf("READ:%zd/%d expected bytes, MSG:<<%s>>\n", n, nMsgSize[i] - 1, msgs[i].msg);
```